# Why Live Server is not opening the browser or loading

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am new to VSCode and Web Designing. I downloaded live server to load my websites directly, but when i click on golive then nothing happens. No browser opens up and even if I open it manually then click on go live nothing happens. I have auto save turned on to 1000ms so then it must work right? I am using latest stable version of VSCode and latest version of live server(OS Windows 8). Please help me if you can I am trying to open it in Google Chrome. Here is my settings.json -

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encounter the same problem but when I go to the live server setting. at the **Live Server › Settings: Https** I changed the value of enable to false. Then it works fine with chrome. Otherwise you have to change the https to http because others browser use http for the link
PS: make sure you install live-server extension in chrome also

Answer (score 0):

this is happening to me, and It opens the tab but won't load even after 24+ hours. You have to close VS and the browser tab, then open VS again and wait to open live server. However long you have to wait is dependent on how good your computer is.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you have added insufficient paths in your Environmental variables.

1. First you can do is close the vs code
2. Go to the properties of My Pc
3. Click on Advanced Settings
4. click on Environmental Variables
5. from there you can add path clicking the path variables in the table shown there
   6 . Add a new line to the path and copy paste the path of your system 32

   C:\Windows\System32

hope this solution works in your case